# Java Card framework.exp not found

Tags: java, ubuntu, javacard

I start with JavaCard Development in JavaCard 2.2.2 on Linux. The Java Class is build with Java 1.5 as it's the standard for JC 2.2.2. When trying to convert the class to CAP File with the following command, the script doesn't work becaus e of the following error. Even when giving explicit path to the file .

```
sudo ./converter  -out CAP -exportpath /javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2/api_export_files/javacard/framework/javacard/framework.exp -classdir ~/Documents/work/smartcards/hello_smartcard/out/production/hello_smartcard/ hello_smartcard 0x01:0x01:0x01:0x01:0x01 1.0
```

> error: export file framework.exp of package javacard.framework not
>   found.

### Update

I looked deeper into the given code and found that the error occurs on the following Line of code:

```
JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JFLAGS com.sun.javacard.converter.Converter "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the answer myself, with the help of this one: http://www.protectdigitalassets.com/?p=11

**create File called hello_smartcard.opt**

> -out EXP JCA CAP
>   -exportpath /javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2/api_export_files
>   -classdir /home/florian/Documents/work/smartcards/hello_smartcard/src/
>   -applet  0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x1:0x1 hello_smartcard hello_smartcard 0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x1 1.0

**create CAP from config**

```
/javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2/bin/converter -config hello_smartcard.opt
```

**create ADPU Commands with scriptgen**

```
/javacard/java_card_kit-2_2_2/bin/scriptgen javacard/hello_smartcard.cap -o javacard/hello_smartcard.gen
```